# How to keep TFS running fast?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Over 4 years of continuously using TFS 2010, the system becomes very slow now. It takes almost 1 minute to save 1 update for a bug. I tried to delete unused workspaces, shelvesets, labels and build outputs but the system is still slow.

Does anyone else has similar problem?

What else could I do to make TFS run faster?

Is there a maintenance guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't sound like a TFS problem so much as a PC problem. (The basic spec suggested for a TFS server is pretty low, and is allegedly sufficient for up to 500 users which suggests it should be pretty scalable)

Here are some suggestions:

- Make sure you have installed all updates.
- Check for free disk space, disk fragmentation, and clean out your temporary folders and log files. (In particular TFS build has a habit of forgetting to delete temp files, the IIS web cache can easily grow to 50GB+, and only last week I found that IIS/SharePoint/SQL logs were using over 50GB on my server! All these things grow continuously and will eventually cause the PC to grind to a halt if you don't keep cleaning them up unfortunately)
- Check that there are no other processes running on your server (e.g. antivirus scans or database backups) that might affect performance.
- Check network settings - our TFS server was very slow at one point until I realised it was resolving local addresses through a proxy server on the other side of the planet, introducing huge unnecessary delays. So check that DNS and AD are working cleanly on the machine/domain. Check that you get a fast connection between your client pc's and the server.
- Reporting bugs is mostly an SQL database operation, so search this question with respect to Sql performance rather than TFS.

At the worst you could backup your tfs databases, reinstall the pc, and restore them to be sure as much as possible is clean and new, but that is a drastic measure. last resort, proceed with caution. And if you go this far, consider upgrading to TFS 2013.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try everything you say. If any of the suggestions above could bring TFS back to speed, I will mark this answer as a solution.  Thanks

Comment: Good luck. I've tidied up (and slightly elaborated) my answer now that I'm on a PC rather than my phone :-)